# Bigcommerce API - Create Shipment - Include all Items

Tags: bigcommerce

according to the documentation, the [Create Shipment](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders/shipments#create-a-shipment) method requires the property "items" - an array of the items being shipped, for example:

```
{
  "tracking_number": "EJ958083578US",
  "comments": "Ready to go...",
  "order_address_id": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "order_product_id": 15,
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In our business, a shipment almost invariably contains ALL items from the relevant order.

That being the case, is there a way to create a shipment without listing all items (which would require iterating over the product line-items)?  Or, alternatively, a way to include all items by default (without iterating)?

We are simply wishing to automate the process of [adding tracking numbers to orders](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Importing-Tracking-Numbers) - which (as a manual process) involves uploading a csv with [order_number: tracking_number] - i.e. it self-evidently assumes that all items are being shipped.  The API seems not to include that (very sensible) option, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Cripes.  "Grumpy old developer" is right.  But, of course, you are quite correct.  Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From Bigcommerce Support:*

There is not a way to add a tracking number without adding a shipment nor a way to default the shipment to include all products. This is a helpful suggestion though that I will be passing on to our Product Team for possible implementation into future versions of the API.

Unfortunately for now it is necessary that you GET to the products subresource of an order and iterate over all of the products to pull their 'id' values and 'order_address_id' values so you can generate your POST request to the shipment subresource. It is not necessary to make a GET request to the shipping address subresource directly unless you want the details of that shipping address. It is also not necessary to make a GET request to the base order object unless you want details found there or you are looking to automate the process of checking for orders ready to ship.

So assuming you know an order ID that you want to ship it should only take 2 requests total to both GET the products subresource and then POST to the shipment resource.